# Access Dlookup it shows me an error or empty field

Tags: microsoft-access

I would like the form to show me the amount from the query by name in the field.
This shows me an error or an empty field:

```
=DLookUp("[Výpočet vaplacené peníze od číšníků Dotaz]![Sum Of Vyplaceno]";
         "[Výpočet vaplacené peníze od číšníků Dotaz]";
         "[Jméno_Tabulka výplaty manažer 1].[Column](1)"=
         "[Výpočet vaplacené peníze od číšníků Dotaz]![Personál jméno]"
        )
```

[image: Access]

Comment: Can you translate the errors to English, please?

Comment: #error in field. :(